# MySQL reporting error at row negative 1 (row -1) - why?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

Why is MySQL reporting an error at row -1 for some values? And why is it reporting it for column ''?

I'm not asking how to handle these errors, just wondering why MySQL does this. Is there some justification for reporting an error for a value that doesn't exist, for a column and row that don't exist?

Below, I just have a single empty string in a table. But the same error happens with alpha characters, e.g. 'B'.

With values like '5 1/2' or '5ABCD', I only get the `1292 Truncated...` error, not the 1366 error.

MySQL  8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 - (Ubuntu)

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `temp_test_dec` (
  `source_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  KEY `source_value` (`source_value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

mysql> INSERT INTO `temp_test_dec` VALUES('');

mysql> SELECT CAST(source_value AS DECIMAL(9,3)) as dec_val FROM `temp_test_dec`;
+---------+
| dec_val |
+---------+
|   0.000 |
+---------+
1 row in set, 2 warnings (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                              |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect DECIMAL value: '0' for column '' at row -1 |
| Warning | 1292 | Truncated incorrect DECIMAL value: ''                |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Additional 1366 error is reported for empty string only. This is inner function error mark which is relative to a value, not a row, so neither column nor row number are defined during this error.